# chrome headless browser not opening URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am running my script on chrome headless browser and it is not launching the url.

**chrome Version : 70.0 , chromedriver: 2.44**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");`
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get(url);
```

above code works on any other url's but one which i want to launch is not openning. This code is able to launch the url in phantomjs and also chrome without headless.

When trying to get source of the page in headless browser i am getting.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Any help appriciated.

Comment: could you provide more information?

Comment: Where did you find _chromedriver: 3.8.1_? Which url are you trying to access?

Comment: typo mistake , chromedriver is 2.44

Comment: @PrasantaBiswas - what additional info. are you looking for ?

Comment: what URL you are trying to access?